# Error on invoking the REST API to Update paragraph

Tags: postman, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin 0.7.3 version . On trying to use the zeppelin REST API call(http://localhost:8080/api/notebook/2D8BSC25C/paragraph/20180211-213728_2111839943)in postman to update paragraph , am getting the Method not allowed error eventhough the given input were correct.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't show the error, or describe the code or config that is responsible for whatever it is that you are doing. Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to include the details _anyone_ would need to help you.  Also, show what research you have done regarding "zeppelin method not found" in relation to your specific case. This is a very common message among Zeppelin users.

Answer (score 1):

In version 0.7.3 you can only update paragraph configuration -> [docs](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#update-paragraph-configuration]).

The full paragraph update will be available in the future releases.

Comment: Thank you Max,                                                                                     But the paragraph is being updated in zeppelin 0.7.3 so i would like to know how it is working.